# Connecting Google Cloud Flex App Engine to HA VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, vpn

We have a google cloud app engine in flex environment running node JS. The application needs to call an AWS web service that is private. To access the private web service, we have been asked to use a VPN tunnel.

Using the following instructions, we successfully established a HA VPN with 4 tunnels. The tunnels shows correct green "established" checkmark status for the tunnel and the BGP session.

https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/tutorials/create-ha-vpn-connections-google-cloud-aws

The App engine is connected to the subnet where the VPN is connected via the following entry in the `app.yaml`

```
network:
   name: custom-vpc
   instance_ip_mode: external
   subnetwork_name: custom-subnet
   session_affinity: true
```

I can nslookup the hostname from the other end of the tunnel, but when I attempt to traceroute to it, the traceroute fails with a bunch of "***" and no traffic seems to pass through the tunnel. I have added a firewall rule to all traffic from any destination through the subnet. What am I missing here? Any recommendation on how to diagnose?

Comment: Your issue appears to be a routing problem. Launch a regular Compute Engine VM in `custom-subnet`. You can then use normal IP tools to test connectivity over the VPN. Update your post with the tests and results.

Comment: Thanks John, I was doing that this morning. I still don't have a clue. I suspect a routing issue, too. I think I need to some reading to figure out how the routing works.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue was because we were referencing the global address of the target. As a result, the routing went to the internet instead of the URL. Since a global address was available, we had the requirement change so that we update the firewall and not use the VPN. In any case, the VPN was actually working properly.